# Remote debugging Tomcat with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I can't seem to debug the tomcat application through Eclipse.  I've set

`CATALINA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n`

and then I run `bin/catalina.sh`, where I see output saying it's listening for `dt_socket` on `port 8000`.  But whenever I try to connect to port `8000` in Eclipse (by adding an entry in the remote java application menu), it complains about a refused connect.  Any ideas?

Comment: can you please post your remote configuration used in eclipse.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Can you check if this works?

```
JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"

catalina.sh jpda start
```

Comment: It does about the same thing, but I still can't attach to the VM.  Eclipse doesn't actually give any output about anything - the first time I select my remote application, it doesn't throw an error, but I don't see any responses or anything.  The second time I try to debug that app, it throws the refused connection error.

Comment: Actually, yours did fix it.  Eclipse doesn't actually say anything when it successfully connects, and reconnecting a second time forces the error.  So it was working, but I just didn't notice.

Comment: This is for those in Windows OS: `set JPDA_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n` `catalina.bat jpda start`

Comment: What does suspend=n option does?

Comment: @Trismegistos. `suspend` specifies whether the jvm should wait for debugger or continue.  See [this doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/conninv.html).

Comment: Actually `catalina.sh jpda start` should be enough. The catalina.sh has a couple of `JPDA_*` parameters which can be used to for example change port, see the file for documentation.

Comment: Another way is to create setenv.bat under tomcat\bin. Then add     
    
    set JPDA_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y

in windows OS

Comment: 1. JPDA_OPTS value can also be set into CATALINA_OPTS \n 2. "catalina.sh jpda start" is in /tomcat/bin/startup.sh "exec "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" jpda start "$@""

Comment: I just followed this , and this really works :- 

http://easybook4u.com/index.php/2017/07/08/how-to-remotely-debug-a-java-web-application-deployed-on-amazon-ec2/

Answer (score 56):

I spent some time on this to get the right information.

So here is the detailed information step by step.

Environment : Windows 7

TomCat version : 7.0

IDE : Eclipse

Configurations to be added for enabling remote debugging with in tomcat is

```
-Xdebug
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
```

I don't recommend above configuration fro non windows environment.
To add the above configuration double click on tomcat server which will be available in server view. Find the below screen shot.
[image]

Now add the above runtime environment configuration to tomcat. For this check below screenshot.

[image]

Now got to Arugments tab in Edit launch configuration properties as show in below screen shot.

[image]

GoTo VM arguments section add these lines.

> -Xdebug
>
> -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n

[image]

Now got to debug button available on eclipse toolbar.

[image]

In Debug configurations find "Remote Java Application" and double click on it.[image]

In Name field enter any name which you like to.

From project field using browse button select the project which you want to perform remote debug.

The hostname is nothing but the host address. Here i'm working locally so it is "localhost".

Last the Port column the value should be 8000. Apart from Name and Project text fields other two columns Host and port will be filled by eclipse itself if not make you have same values as mentioned. Check Screen shot for info.[image]

Now right click on TomcatServer in server console select Add and Remove from context menu. From this dialog you can add the project to server.

Now run the Tomcat sever.

[image]

Now run the TomCatDebugConfiguration from Debug Tool.

Last open internal or external browser and run your project. If the execution control reached the break points then the eclipse will prompt for debug perspective.

Comment: Failed to connect to remote VM, connect timed out, any idea ?

Comment: Your failed to connect is due to the address put address=*:8000

Answer (score 54):

In the tomcat bin directory where`catalina.bat` or `.sh` is found (aka {CATALINA_BASE}/bin), edit (create if not there):

```
setenv.bat/.sh
```

Add the following line:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"
```

That's all you need to do, you don't need to edit the `catalina.bat` (or `.sh`) file.

See the comments in `catalina.bat`or `catalina.sh`.

You may have to adjust the syntax for your particular environment/situation.  For example, if you already have CATALINA_OPTS defined, you might do something like this (in a windows environment):

```
set CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8088,server=y,suspend=n
```

To debug from Eclipse:

run->Debug configurations...->Remote Java Application->New

and specify a name, the project you are debugging, and the tomcat host and debug port specified above.

Comment: This is working you will need to set this CATALINA_OPTS in setenv.sh which is in tomcat/bin directory. Thanks.

Comment: In my setenv.bat it was JAVA_OPTS (tomcat 7)

Comment: Hello Philip, added some notes that might help, if not: which os, tomcat, and eclipse versions are you using?

Comment: in `setenv.bat`  in the `bin` directory put a line like `set JPDA_OPTS= -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=8000,suspend=n` , use `startup.bat` to start tomcat

Comment: Java 11 update, specify a wildcard for the address=*:8000.

Answer (score 35):

In `catalina.bat` file please modify the below.

- Step 1: `CATALINA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"`
- Step 2: `JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"`
- Step 3: Run Tomcat from command prompt like below: `catalina.sh jpda start`
- Step 4: Then in the eclipse create a debug configuration

  1. Give any name for configuration.
  2. Give the `project name`.
  3. Give the connection type as `Standard(Socket Attach)`
  4. host as `localhost`
  5. port as `8000`( or any port number , but that should be same in other places also).

Comment: I have found CATALINA_OPTS in the following parts at catalina.bat,
      :doStop
      shift
      set ACTION=stop
      set CATALINA_OPTS=
      goto execCmd

      :doConfigTest
      shift
      set ACTION=configtest
      set CATALINA_OPTS=
      goto execCmd

 where to edit it? Can you just upload the contents of your catalina.bat?

Comment: Seems like you are writing the same thing twice. I skipped your step 1 - and it works. Can you confirm there's no need to change CATALINA_OPTS ?

Comment: for the diff between see CATALINA_OPTS & JPDA_OPTS see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222365/catalina-opts-vs-java-opts-what-is-the-difference

Comment: THis will not work in Tomcat 8.  In order for it to work in Tomcat 8, you have to leave out step 1.

Comment: @RAJ. It worked totally in Tomcat 6. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9):

Many of the above answers are correct, but remember that by default the debugger will listen on **localhost**, which means you can debug only if you're running the debugging client (for example, the IDE) on the same machine.

If you are debugging a **remote server** you will need to specify the correct IP address on that server to listen on, for example

> JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=**10.1.1.33**:8000,server=y,suspend=n"
>
> catalina.sh jpda start

Note that the address is now **10.1.1.33**:8000

Of course, you can also check which IP is actually being used, by running

> netstat -an

This command is valid on both windows and Linux - you just need to filter out the port with `find` (Windows) or `grep` (Linux).

Comment: I think you mean which **PORT** is actually being used not which **IP**.

Comment: No, I mean "IP address". If you do remote debugging (from another machine) you need to be able to specify an IP address which is different from localhost or 127.0.0.1. Of course you will always also need the port number.

Answer (score 5):

Just run `./catalina.sh jpda start` (forks) or `./catalina.sh jpda run` (does not fork, not mentioned in help). All options mentioned here default to sane values.

Answer (score 5):

Let me share the simple way to enable the remote debugging mode in tomcat7 with eclipse (Windows).

Step 1: open bin/startup.bat file
Step 2: add the below lines for debugging with JDPA option (it should starting line of the file )

```
    set JPDA_ADDRESS=8000  
    set JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
```

Step 3: in the same file .. go to end of the file modify this line -

```
    call "%EXECUTABLE%" jpda start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%  
    instead of line  
    call "%EXECUTABLE%" start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
```

step 4: then just run bin>startup.bat
 (so now your tomcat server ran in remote mode with port 8000).

step 5: after that lets connect your source project by eclipse IDE with remote client.

step6: In the Eclipse IDE go to "debug Configuration"

step7:click "remote java application" and on that click "New"

step8. in the "connect" tab set the parameter value

```
   project= your source project  
   connection Type: standard (socket attached)   
   host: localhost  
   port:8000
```

step9: click apply and debug.

so finally your eclipse remote client is connected with the running tomcat server (debug mode).

Hope this approach might be help you.

Regards..

Answer (score 4):

Modify catalina.bat to add

```
set JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"
```

and

```
CATALINA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
```

Optional: Add below line to run the debug mode by default when you run startup.bat

```
call "%EXECUTABLE%" jpda start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
```

Eclipse or STS select debug configuration right click -> new

```
connection type -> Standard socket Attach
Port -> 8000 (as given in the CATALINA_OPTS)
Host -> localhost or IP address
```

Comment: This information is for WINDOWS, but I just so happened to be on windows and so it helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If still all the above doen't work you can always add to the script

```
    set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"
```

Answer (score 2):

In tomcat 7, catalina.sh has this code:

```
if [ "$1" = "jpda" ] ; then
  if [ -z "$JPDA_TRANSPORT" ]; then
    JPDA_TRANSPORT="dt_socket"
  fi
  if [ -z "$JPDA_ADDRESS" ]; then
    JPDA_ADDRESS="8000"
  fi
  if [ -z "$JPDA_SUSPEND" ]; then
    JPDA_SUSPEND="n"
  fi
  if [ -z "$JPDA_OPTS" ]; then
    JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=$JPDA_TRANSPORT,address=$JPDA_ADDRESS,server=y,suspend=$JPDA_SUSPEND"
  fi
  CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS $JPDA_OPTS"
  shift
fi
```

Ii implies that you can setup JPDA with:

```
export JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
export JPDA_ADDRESS=8000
export JPDA_SUSPEND=n
```

Or with:

```
JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"
```

And finally use:

`catalina.sh jpda start`

Regards

Comment: Tomcat 8: The JPDA_ variables can be set in setenv.sh without the need to 'export' them. In any case the first param of startup call must be 'jpda'. If you start tomcat as service, best is to modify the ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/startup.sh script, add the 'jpda' param in the last line before 'start': ´´exec "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" jpda start "$@"´´.

Answer (score 1):

For apache-tomcat-8.5.28 version just do this,

```
catalina.bat jpda start
```

As the default settings already configured for us in catalina.bat as

> if not "%JPDA_OPTS%" == "" goto gotJpdaOpts set
>   JPDA_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=%JPDA_TRANSPORT%,address=%JPDA_ADDRESS%,server=y,suspend=%JPDA_SUSPEND%

So no need of any other config. And when you execute command   catalina.bat jpda start, you can see debug port 8000 is opened.

Answer (score 1):

I was hitting this issue while running Tomcat inside of a Docker container.  To fix this make sure you add the '-p 8000:8000' argument in your docker run command to expose this port to your local machine.  You will of course need the setenv.sh file in your ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/ within your container as well.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the startup.bat with the CATALINA_OPTS AND JPDA_OPTS didn't work for me but adding them to catalina.bat did

1. Modify catalina.bat

CATALINA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"

JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"

2. Modify startup.bat to include jpda

change call "%EXECUTABLE%" start %CMD_LINE_ARGS% to

call "%EXECUTABLE%" jpda start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%

Then configure remote java application in your debug configurations in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you open catalina.bat with text editor, you see that:
"Do not set the variables in this script....." So never change it in that script, instead you can do below steps:

1. It advices you to create a new bat file with name "setenv.bat".
2. Then set 2 variables in that bat file such as:

   set CATALINA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"

   set JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"
3. Lastly run that at cmd that: "catalina.bat jpda start"
4. In IDE, create remote debug configuration and set host to related server ip and port to 8000.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer for issues I had with Java 8 and Tomcat 9:  [Java remote debugging (JPDA) not working for me in Tomcat 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54373166/java-remote-debugging-jpda-not-working-for-me-in-tomcat-9/55689736#55689736)

This is similar to @DAB's warning, and his solution is likely more secure.

Answer (score -2):

For apache-tomcat-8.5.28

modify `JDPA_OPTS` like the below then run like `catalina.bat jpda start`

```
JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=$JPDA_TRANSPORT,address=$JPDA_ADDRESS,server=y,suspend=$JPDA_SUSPEND"
JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=$JPDA_TRANSPORT,address=8000,server=y,suspend=$JPDA_SUSPEND"
```