# Start tomcat 6 in debug mode?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, tomcat6

How to start the tomcat 6 server in debug mode and use it with Eclipse Ide for remote debugging. ?

Right now i am using command line to start the server :

tomcat6.exe

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remote debugging Tomcat with Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835612/remote-debugging-tomcat-with-eclipse)

Comment: I am using tomcat6.exe while in that post it is given for catalina.bat.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to debug using tomcat as a service(with "tomcat6.exe") but it's really easy to do with "catalina.bat".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the tomcat6.exe version you can enable remote debugging by running the tomcat6w.exe application and adding the following 2 java options in the list on the Java tab:

```
-Xdebug
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
```

It worked in my case (Tomcat 6.0.26 for windows).

The Apache Tomcat wiki describes the topic in detail: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/Developing#Developing-Debugging

Comment: Can you take me through the complete steps to configure remote debugging in tomcat6 using Eclipse.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061590/gwt-eclipse-remote-debug-in-tomcat-6

Answer (score 1):

As you are using eclipse goto Windows-> Show view -> Add Server.

Choose Perspective as Debug from Windows-> Open Perspective -> Debug

Then Right click on added server and start it in debug mode.