# How to start debug mode from command prompt for apache tomcat server?

Tags: java, tomcat

I want to start debug mode for my application. But I need to start the debug mode from command prompt. Is it possible ? And will the procedure vary between tomcat 5.5 to tomcat 6.?

Comment: catalina.bat jpda start

Comment: possible duplicate of [Start tomcat 6 in debug mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458212/start-tomcat-6-in-debug-mode)

Answer (score 137):

On windows

```
$ catalina.bat jpda start
```

On Linux/Unix

```
$ catalina.sh jpda start
```

More info `---->` https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/Developing

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to setup the debug option in `startup.sh`. Editing the last line in `tomcat/bin/startup.sh` to `exec "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" jpda start "$@"`. I always forget to start in debug mode and I can save a 5minute restart.

Answer (score 60):

For windows first set variables:

```
set JPDA_ADDRESS=8000
set JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
```

to start server in debug mode:

```
%TOMCAT_HOME%/bin/catalina.bat jpda start
```

For unix first export variables:

```
export JPDA_ADDRESS=8000
export JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
```

and to start server in debug mode:

```
%TOMCAT_HOME%/bin/catalina.sh jpda start
```

Comment: um yes, although 8000 and dt_socket are mentioned as defaults in catalina.bat, you actually have to set them as in the above post :/

Comment: to the point answer and It worked for me +1. saved my day

Answer (score 29):

1. From your IDE, create a remote debug configuration, configure it for the default JPDA Tomcat port which is port 8000.
2. From the command line:

   Linux:

   ```
   cd apache-tomcat/bin
   export JPDA_SUSPEND=y
   ./catalina.sh jpda run
   ```

   Windows:

   ```
   cd apache-tomcat\bin
   set JPDA_SUSPEND=y
   catalina.bat jpda run
   ```
3. Execute the remote debug configuration from your IDE, and Tomcat will start running and you are now able to set breakpoints in the IDE.

Note:

The `JPDA_SUSPEND=y` line is optional, it is useful if you want that Apache Tomcat doesn't start its execution until step 3 is completed, useful if you want to troubleshoot application initialization issues.

Answer (score 16):

A short answer is to add the following options when the JVM is started.

```
JAVA_OPTS=" $JAVA_OPTS -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8080"
```

Comment: When using JAVA_OPTS -Xdebug you need not start catalina with jpda. Otherwise you may end up with this `ERROR: Cannot load this JVM TI agent twice, check your java command line for duplicate jdwp options.`

Answer (score 6):

First, Navigate to the `TOMCAT-HOME/bin` directory.

Then, Execute the following in the command-line:

```
catalina.bat jpda start
```

If the Tomcat server is running under Linux, just invoke the `catalina.sh` program

```
catalina.sh jpda start
```

It's the same for Tomcat 5.5 and Tomcat 6

Comment: Can you tell me the equivalent of Tomcat 7.0?

Answer (score 4):

These instructions worked for me on apache-tomcat-8.5.20 on mac os 10.13.3 using jdk1.8.0_152:

```
$ cd /path/to/apache-tomcat-8.5.20/bin
$ export JPDA_ADDRESS="localhost:12321"
$ ./catalina.sh jpda run
```

Now connect to port 12321 from IntelliJ/Eclipse and enjoy remote debugging.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to run tomcat in debug mode

1. Using jdpa run
2. Using JAVA_OPTS

First setup the environment. Then start the server using following commands.

```js
export JPDA_ADDRESS=8000

export JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket

%TOMCAT_HOME%/bin/catalina.sh jpda start

sudo catalina.sh jpda start
```

refer this [article](https://tharinduketipe.wordpress.com/2015/05/21/how-to-run-apache-tomcat-in-debug-mode-ubuntu/) for more information this is clearly define it

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to do this via powershell on windows this worked for me

$env:JPDA_SUSPEND="y"

$env:JPDA_TRANSPORT="dt_socket"

/path/to/tomcat/bin/catalina.bat jpda start

Answer (score 0):

Inside catalina.bat set the port on which you wish to start the debugger

```
if not "%JPDA_ADDRESS%" == "" goto gotJpdaAddress
set JPDA_ADDRESS=9001
```

Then you can simply start the debugger with

```
catalina.bat jpda
```

Now from Eclipse or IDEA select remote debugging and start start debugging by connecting to port 9001.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep this always when your service is running, you should edit your `bin/startup.sh`. There add 'jpda' parameter right here

```
exec "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" jpda  start "$@"
```

instead of original

```
exec "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" start "$@"
```