# How can i start my Tomcat 8 in Debug mode which is Installed in "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\"

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

My Project is in Eclipse Helios and I have to run my application in Tomcat 8,
The problem is Eclipse Helios is an older version so It is not supporting to set up Tomcat 8 in servers tab of Eclipse.

I am facing lot of issues while developing and testing, so I am willing to start Tomcat 8 in debug mode can any one please suggest me in this regard.

My goal is to start tomcat in debug mode without Setting it up in eclipse and I should be able to debug my application, I tried in multiple ways but unable to solve this issue can any one please suggest me in this regard.

Regards,
Nithin.

Comment: please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689274/how-to-start-debug-mode-from-command-prompt-for-apache-tomcat-server) and see if some of it has helped

Comment: Is there a reason you have to stay on Helios?

Comment: No specified reason I will try with some eclipse new version.

Answer (score 0):

** Copied answer **

With the tomcat6.exe version you can enable remote debugging by running the tomcat6w.exe application and adding the following 2 java options in the list on the Java tab:

`-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n`

This is according to http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing and it worked in my case (Tomcat 6.0.26 for windows)

Comment: Thank you Darshan Kumar I will try this and will get back to you.

Comment: Hi  Darshan Kumar I tried with above solution but I am unable to debug the application I have given debug break points in my eclipse.

Comment: is the port number matching ?