# Is there any way that i can pass debug breakpoints from command prompt to apache tomcat that is running my java web application?

Tags: java, maven, debugging, web-applications, command

I have used JDB to debug java application from command prompt.Is there a similar process on debugging java web application?I dont't want any IDE's involved in this process.I just need to pass my break points or method that need to be debugged from command prompt .

Comment: I'm sure you can connect JDB and similar to a running JVM process remotely.  However I don't think you can do it through Apache.  You'll have to enable a connection to the JDB port on the network firewall and the JVM, or use a VPN or similar.

Comment: Debug the servlet container.

Comment: so how do i pass the debug breakpoints then ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start debug mode from command prompt for apache tomcat server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689274/how-to-start-debug-mode-from-command-prompt-for-apache-tomcat-server)

Comment: you want to enable remote debugging in the launcher script of tomcat. see the captioned post. also, have a look in the `bin/catalina.[sh|bat]` file; you see that enabling `JPDA` options, Tomcat will listen for remote debug connections.