# How do I debug web app on AWS environment using Eclipse JEE?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-applications, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, remote-debugging, eclipse-jee

I want to debug my web app. In Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers Version 2019-03(4.11.0), I right-click on my web project and select Debug As->Debug on Server. I choose an existing server then click Finish. A dialog appears and I choose the Switch mode option and click on OK. Then I get a dialog that asks for a remote debugging port with some instructions. It says:

> Please note: to connect to remote debugger, the debug port will be opened for TCP ingress on your EC2 security group.

What else would I need to do? I've never done this before?

Comment: Why not just debug locally?

Comment: @markwalker_ I’m running into other issues debugging locally. I can’t even run my web app locally. I was able to at least run my web app remotely.

Comment: If you can't run it locally why did you even push it remotely? I can't imagine maintaining a system that wouldn't run locally. You can't assume something will run if you can't run it locally. And you can't really connect to the AWS server from your IDE safely.

Comment: The local tomcat server won’t start. I’ll be posting a question on Stack Overflow for that issue later. I had gotten it started at one time, but I left off and just recently started on the project again.

Answer (score 1):

If your JVM is running on EC2 on AWS; it would be debugging just like u would do locally.. Only difference is that it will be slower ( because it on cloud ) and debugging port should be open on SecurityGroup of EC2.

Hence on EC2; while starting java; use these options as mentioned on [What are Java command line options to set to allow JVM to be remotely debugged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138511/what-are-java-command-line-options-to-set-to-allow-jvm-to-be-remotely-debugged)

When you start in debug mode through Eclipse; it automatically gives those options.

You might be using tomcat; hence u would have to give those options in JAVA_OPTS

Comment: I'm totally new to this. I don't do anything to start java on EC2, hence I don't know where to put those command line options. I am using tomcat, and I don't know where to put the JAVA_OPTS options.

Comment: @DanielBrower https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689274/how-to-start-debug-mode-from-command-prompt-for-apache-tomcat-server