# Debugger failing to attach

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I'm trying to remote debug a Tomcat. I added `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005` to `JAVA_OPTS` and restarted Tomcat. IntelliJ wasn't able to attach. So I tried `telnet thehost 5005` and it seemed I was initially attached but then my session was terminated with `Connection closed by foreign host` and `catalina.out` had `Debugger failed to attach: timeout during handshake`. Same thing happened if I did `telnet localhost 5005` on the remote machine.

If I do `netstat -antp | grep 5005` on the remote machine I get

`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5005            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26745/java-tomcat12`

So it seems the JVM is listening. What am I doing wrong?

**Update**: using the same options I can debug a very simple hello world like application which I run on the remote server. So it seems it's something specific to Tomcat, or at least this specific web application.

Comment: Have you tried with `-Xdebug` ?
[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36420167/5810894)

Comment: It's java 8, `-Xdebug` is for earlier versions I believe.

Comment: Oh, my bad. You are correct!

Comment: Not sure why but the debugger only allows attaching from the same host, so I had to create a SSH tunnel from my computer to the remote host. BTW, I mistakenly thought that telnet connecting and then terminating the session was a bad sign but it just meant that the JVM is listening and all is good.