# Access Tomcat debug port outside container

Tags: spring, docker, tomcat, remote-debugging, tomcat9

I have a container running java backend on a tomcat server. I would like to configure it so that I can attach my eclipse to debug my code.
There is a lot of documentation but with so many different and contradictory answers, I can't find a way to do it.

here is my current configuration :

DockerFile :

```
From tomcat:9.0-jdk8-openjdk
   
ADD ./application.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
ADD tomcat-users.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml
ADD server.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml
EXPOSE 9090
CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

And the command to run the docker :

`docker run -d -p 9090:8080 myApp`

What should I add to make my application accessible to remote debugging ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start debug mode from command prompt for apache tomcat server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689274/how-to-start-debug-mode-from-command-prompt-for-apache-tomcat-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution I found was :
DockerFile

```
From tomcat:9.0-jdk8-openjdk
   
ADD ./application.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
ADD tomcat-users.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml
ADD server.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml
EXPOSE 9090
EXPOSE 9000
ENV JPDA_ADDRESS=8000
ENV JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket

CMD ["catalina.sh", "jpda", "run"]
```

and then :
`docker run -d -p 9090:8080 -p 9000:8000  myApp` after building the image.

**Warning :** this makes the application debuggable **only** from the server where the docker is running (in `localhost:9000` in that example)! I read there is something to do with `*:JPDA_ADDRESS` but I could not make it work.

Comment: `JPDA_ADDRESS=8000` works only up to Java 8 (cf. [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-application-remote-debugging)). A more universal solution would be `JPDA_ADDRESS=*:8000`. Remark also that you are exporting the wrong ports: in should be `EXPOSE 8080` and `EXPOSE 8000`.

Comment: well no I expose the mapped port (look at the `docker run`  command below). I will try with `*:`

Comment: Yes, you override the default port mappings, however the purpose of `EXPOSE` is to give default port mappings (cf. [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose).

Comment: OK I learned something.. So it is basically "useless" to put the `EXPOSE` command ? It acts as documentation ?