# Where to specify Tomcat Timezone on startup?

Tags: java, tomcat, centos, amazon-linux

Where should I specify Tomcat timezone (-Duser.timezone=America/Los_Angeles) on startup? Should it be CATALINA_OPTS or JAVA_OPTS?

I am using Tomcat 8.5.37 on Linux.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the setenv.sh which is located at CATALINA_HOME/bin/. Set the CATALINA_OPTS

Comment: Thanks. Can you clarify? Why not to use JAVA_OPTS?

Comment: Please refer to the link. You will get an understanding. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222365/catalina-opts-vs-java-opts-what-is-the-difference