# debugging project without eclipse debugger

Tags: apache, maven, tomcat7

I am using  maven project in eclipse  mars . My Project is not building in the  eclipse so i am  compiling my project through dos mode. I not being able to debug the code.so somebody please help me to solve  issue

Comment: Care to explain your issue ? What do you want to debug, is it a webapp ? On which server are you deploying it ? (Are you creating a war/jar using maven ? ant ?)

Comment: I want to debug my bean sample.java to check the list  is populating correct value to database or not . I am using tomcat 7  server  and i am creating the war from maven

Answer (score 1):

You can debug a tomcat server even if you don't run it inside Eclipse, using [remote debug](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcremdbug.htm).

Please take a look at [Remote debugging Tomcat with Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835612/remote-debugging-tomcat-with-eclipse) or [this blog for Intellij](http://blog.trifork.com/2014/07/14/how-to-remotely-debug-application-running-on-tomcat-from-within-intellij-idea/) / [this one for Eclipse](http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/tomcat-tcat-server/debugging-your-tomcat-webapp-with-eclipse/)

The idea is to start your tomcat server [in debug mode](https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/BOOT/Setting+Up+Tomcat+For+Remote+Debugging) then connecting your debugger to the "remote" (even if on your local PC) JVM (The JVM of the server).