# Deploy maven project to localhost and debug in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have quite big project and I want to debug it in Eclipse. My project contains main package and few dependencies, everything linked with maven. I can 'mvn package' this, make .war file, deploy to tomcat and everything works fine but it is time consuming. Now I want to do the same thing - deploy to localhost but also add possibility of debugging. So basically I want to click "debug" on my project, open browser > localhost, do some tests and see results in Eclipse.
Problem is I cannot find any good tutorial or configuration guide. Can anyone link something?

Comment: maven packaging and can be done from eclipse quite easily and also for opening local host and run your testcase, you create a jenkins job. you can integrate that jenkins job to eclipse using https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/hudsonjenkins-mylyn-builds-connector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options

- [Remote debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835612/remote-debugging-tomcat-with-eclipse) (as stated in comments)
- [Import maven project to eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061094/importing-maven-project-into-eclipse) and debug as usual.