# How to debug an application in eclipse which contains 3 war files?

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, maven, tomcat

I'm working in a project which has 3 Maven projects. Each will create 3 separate war files. I've build and deployed the application in Tomcat 8 server by copying the generated war files in Tomcat webapps directory and hit startup.bat.

My question is: How to build it from Eclipse (Mars) and how to debug it from Eclipse.
Since it involves 3 war files I'm not able to do it.

Any solution much appreciated.

Comment: You just need to add the source for all 3 war files, then create a debug config on the Tomcat see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835612/remote-debugging-tomcat-with-eclipse

Comment: Hoping for an answer too. I have one ear and one war in two maven projects, using Intellij, and no idea on how to deploy/debug/jrebel them both at the same time. Currently, when I want to debug one, I deploy the other artifact manually. Quite annoying.

Answer (score 0):

yon can remote debug,the war files is will deploy on the sever(tomcat),you can debug the code you want,if you computer is good,you can open 3 eclipse to debug.