# Using eclipse & tomcat to test a war

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, war

I have several web services packaged as a .war file that is build by ant.  I would like to test these wars as an Eclipse Dynamic Web Service.  All the examples and help I've seen are based on Eclipse building the war file but I've not seen anyone deploy an externally build war file to an Eclipse hosted Tomcat service.

I am aware that you can create a war file from a Eclipse Dynamic Web Service, but since we have multiple developers using multiple IDEs and even multiple platforms the wars need to be created via an IDE agnostic Ant script.

Wars were developed so that a service could be portable.  I just want to plug one into the Eclipse Tomcat Web Server to test.

Thank you but I don't want to create the war from Eclipse (export), nor import a war into my eclipse as a project.  (I know how to do these and they don't do what I want).  I want to deploy a war into a Eclipse/Tomcat service to test.

Thanks for reading this.

Comment: Why must Tomcat be run *by* Eclipse? Is it because you want to debug the code? You can connect Eclipse debugger to an external Tomcat process, you just have to enable debugging of the Tomcat process, see e.g. [Remote debugging Tomcat with Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3835612/5221149), or do a web search for [`tomcat java debug`](https://www.google.com/search?q=tomcat+java+debug) to find lots of example/tutorials for how to do that.

Comment: Correct, remote debugging is an alternative and I've already been implementing it, but I was hoping for something less complicated.  My project involves 11 services, so a little simplication goes a long way.

Comment: In what way is remote debugging that much more compilcated? You already have the `.war` file, so all you need is to configure Tomcat for debugging and add the `.war` file. You of course have to setup Eclipse with all the source files, but you'd have to do that too with Dynamic Web Service, so I don't see the big difference.