# I am trying to remote debug spring MVC application hosted on Ubuntu server from my intellij IDE on MAC

Tags: macos, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, tomcat8, remote-debugging

i started the tomcat by setting below two in setenv.sh file under TOMCAT_HOME/bin/
    export JPDA_ADDRESS="5005"
    export JPDA_TRANSPORT="dt_socket"

```
startd server using sudo ./catalina.sh jpda run the output log says
```

Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005

Created a new remote configuration from edit_configuration and added host name and port start debug and got below error.

5:35 PM Error running 'Remote_Debugging': Unable to open debugger port (xxxxxxxxxx.xxx:5005): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused (Connection refused)"

thanks in advance.

Comment: i also added JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005" in catalina.sh and tried but same error.

Comment: What JDK do you use for running? For JDKs >= 9 you should use `address=*:8001` for remote debug options. See https://dev-aux.com/java/java-local-and-remote-jvm-debugging-jdk-8-and-later See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/55689736/2000323

Comment: Thanks Andrey, after changing the port it's working now.