# How to debug deployed war on tomcat ec2 instance with local eclipse source code

Tags: eclipse, amazon-ec2, debugging, tomcat

I have set up an AWS Linux EC2 instance and install tomcat.
successfully deployed my war file and everything works fine.
I need to connect my development eclipse to remote tomcat for debugging.
how I can connect my local eclipse source code to remote tomcat deployed to war.
I already follow some tricks and tips but unable to connect.

Answer (score 0):

It will help if you can you share error messages or screenshots when you enable debugging while starting your tomcat ([Remote debugging Tomcat with Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835612/remote-debugging-tomcat-with-eclipse)) and assuming your EC2 is reachable to your host running eclipse and you have opened debug port in your security group?